# Image masking and transition on hover other div JavaScript CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Good day!

I have 2 different divs with background images which are clipped by -webkit-clip-path: polygon original page-example:

[image]

```
#model_img{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(/img/blue-eyes-237438_1920.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right;
    background-size:cover;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: left;
    transition: -webkit-clip-path 2s, background-position 2s;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%, 0% 100%);
}

#lens_img{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(/img/lens-490806_1920.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: left;
    transition: -webkit-clip-path 2s, background-position 2s;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 100% 0%);}
```

On hover "Model" or "Photographer" - the diaganal border between images should move to left top or right botoom corner and show "model_im" + hide "lens_img" or show "lens_img" + hide "model_im" respectively.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
      $('#photografer').hover(function() {  
        $('#lens_img').css('-webkit-clip-path', 'polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%)');
        $('#model_img').css('-webkit-clip-path', 'polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%)');
        }, function() {
        // on mouseout, reset the background colour
        $('#model_img').css('-webkit-clip-path', 'polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%, 0% 100%)');
        $('#lens_img').css('-webkit-clip-path', '');
        $('#lens_img').css('background-position', '');
      });
});
     $(function() {
      $('#model').hover(function() {
        $('#model_img').css('-webkit-clip-path', 'polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%)');
        $('#lens_img').css('-webkit-clip-path', 'polygon(100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%)');
        }, function() {
        // on mouseout, reset the background colour
        $('#lens_img').css('-webkit-clip-path', 'polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 100% 0%)');
        $('#model_img').css('-webkit-clip-path', '')
        $('#model_img').css('background-position', '');
      });
});
});
```

I added a bit of jQuery but if you do it fast, the pictures glued to each other (see test picture). I understand that should be some easy solution for it, but i can't find it.

[image]

https://codepen.io/vvohotnikov/pen/zaQyoo - example

The main problem that after hover on links i need only red and blue area movement from one corner to othe. But it also white area shows behind them if you will choose other word quite fast.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve] so that we can actually test this ourselves.

Comment: https://codepen.io/vvohotnikov/pen/zaQyoo

Here i add an example.

The main problem that after hover on links i need only red and blue area movement from one corner to other. But it also white area shows behind them if you will choose other word quite fast.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that you are doing a “hard” switch between those clippaths … When I have hovered over Model and that transition is somewhere “half way”, and then I hover over Photographer - then you start your clipping from the “default” position again, not taking the current state into account.

Comment: https://codepen.io/vvohotnikov/pen/PavLRE

i'm trying to change code, now this page looks much better. But if you will check the code it's looks pretty bad and not correct. If someone have better solution i would be really glad.